# NPE when running Sonar Runner

Tags: sonar-runner, sonarqube-5.0

When running Sonar Runner 2.4 against SonarQube 5.1 RC2 I get this error:

```
ERROR: Error during Sonar runner execution
org.sonar.runner.impl.RunnerException: Unable to execute Sonar
at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.delegateExecution(BatchLauncher.java:91)
at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.run(BatchLauncher.java:75)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.doExecute(BatchLauncher.java:69)
at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.execute(BatchLauncher.java:50)
at org.sonar.runner.api.EmbeddedRunner.doExecute(EmbeddedRunner.java:102)
at org.sonar.runner.api.Runner.execute(Runner.java:100)
at org.sonar.runner.Main.executeTask(Main.java:70)
at org.sonar.runner.Main.execute(Main.java:59)
at org.sonar.runner.Main.main(Main.java:53)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.parse(WindowsPathParser.java:98)
at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.parse(WindowsPathParser.java:77)
at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPath.parse(WindowsPath.java:94)
at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystem.getPath(WindowsFileSystem.java:255)
at sun.nio.fs.AbstractPath.resolve(AbstractPath.java:53)
at org.sonar.api.batch.fs.internal.DefaultInputFile.path(DefaultInputFile.java:72)
at org.sonar.api.batch.fs.internal.DefaultInputFile.file(DefaultInputFile.java:64)
at org.sonar.api.batch.fs.internal.PathPattern$RelativePathPattern.match(PathPattern.java:101)
at org.sonar.batch.scan.filesystem.LanguageDetection.isCandidateForLanguage(LanguageDetection.java:124)
at org.sonar.batch.scan.filesystem.LanguageDetection.language(LanguageDetection.java:97)
at org.sonar.batch.scan.filesystem.InputFileBuilder.completeAndComputeMetadata(InputFileBuilder.java:100)
at org.sonar.batch.scan.filesystem.FileIndexer$1.call(FileIndexer.java:157)
at org.sonar.batch.scan.filesystem.FileIndexer$1.call(FileIndexer.java:154)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Process exited with code 1
Step Start SonarQube Code Analysis (Command Line) failed
```

The same thing works with SonarQube 5.0.1.

Maybe some defensive programming would have been good in Sonar Runner. A NPE does not tell anything meaningful to a user. I suggest that they include an assertion and if there is a problem that a useful exception message is output.

Comment: Any updates on this one? I am running into the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely some sonar property thats expected a directory were defined with something containing "..". Unfortunately, in my tests, sonar expects an absolut path. I had problems in sonar-ant-runner with sonar.sources, sonar.java.binaries and sonar.projectBaseDir properties.

Comment: If you have something to say about a particular question but do not have a solution to the problem, please post it as a comment rather than as an answer.

Comment: I faced the same problem and having '..' in the sonar path properties was the issue. And removing them fixed NPE.