# While running ant task for sonar5.1 using jacoco plugin

Tags: ant, sonarqube, code-coverage, jacoco, sonarqube-scan

**I am new with this sonar code coberage.**
I am trying to genrate code coverage for android unit test.
I am getting below mentioned error while exucuting ant sonar to genrate code coverage.
Sonar configuration is: Sonar5.1 with jacoco

**Error:**

```
org.sonar.runner.impl.RunnerException: Unable to execute Sonar
  at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.delegateExecution(BatchLauncher.java:91)
  at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.run(BatchLauncher.java:75)
  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
  at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.doExecute(BatchLauncher.java:69)
  at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.execute(BatchLauncher.java:50)
  at org.sonar.runner.api.EmbeddedRunner.doExecute(EmbeddedRunner.java:102)
  at org.sonar.runner.api.Runner.execute(Runner.java:100)
  at org.sonar.ant.SonarTask.launchAnalysis(SonarTask.java:51)
  at org.sonar.ant.SonarTask.execute(SonarTask.java:46)
  at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:293)
  at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
  at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
  at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
  at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:435)
  at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:456)
  at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1405)
  at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1376)
  at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
  at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1260)
  at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:853)
  at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:235)
  at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:285)
  at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:112)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
  at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.parse(WindowsPathParser.java:98)
  at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.parse(WindowsPathParser.java:77)
  at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPath.parse(WindowsPath.java:94)
  at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystem.getPath(WindowsFileSystem.java:255)
  at sun.nio.fs.AbstractPath.resolve(AbstractPath.java:53)
  at org.sonar.api.batch.fs.internal.DefaultInputFile.path(DefaultInputFile.java:72)
  at org.sonar.api.batch.fs.internal.DefaultInputFile.file(DefaultInputFile.java:64)
  at org.sonar.api.batch.fs.internal.PathPattern$RelativePathPattern.match(PathPattern.java:101)
  at org.sonar.batch.scan.filesystem.LanguageDetection.isCandidateForLanguage(LanguageDetection.java:124)
  at org.sonar.batch.scan.filesystem.LanguageDetection.language(LanguageDetection.java:97)
  at org.sonar.batch.scan.filesystem.InputFileBuilder.completeAndComputeMetadata(InputFileBuilder.java:100)
  at org.sonar.batch.scan.filesystem.FileIndexer$1.call(FileIndexer.java:157)
  at org.sonar.batch.scan.filesystem.FileIndexer$1.call(FileIndexer.java:154)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Does http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29344554/npe-when-running-sonar-runner#comment56202132_31862969 help you to fix the issue ?

Comment: No, I tried that solution. but no success.